# Docusign Android SDK useTemplate Offline mode does not work

Tags: android, docusignapi

Docusign Android SDK useTemplate Offline mode does not work.
I'm trying to use useTemplate function with isOffline = false, but when I call the function
useTemplate, **it does not respond, neither successful nor error**.

Here is the useTemplate function:

```
private fun useTemplate() {
    templateDelegate.useTemplate(context, templateId, envelopeDefaults, false, object : DSUseTemplateListener {
        override fun onComplete(envelopeId: String) {
            Log.e(DOCUSIGN_TAG, "useTemplate template has been successfully signed")
        }

        override fun onCancel(templateId: String, envelopeId: String?) {
            Log.e(DOCUSIGN_TAG, "useTemplate the signing ceremony is cancelled")
        }

        override fun onError(exception: DSTemplateException) {
            Log.e(DOCUSIGN_TAG, "useTemplate error using the template or during signing")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If 'isOffline' parameter is passed as false in useTemplate api, it should launch Online Signing. Online Signing in SDK is not supported yet and will be available in future releases. We currently have support for Offline Signing. So, you can try passing true for 'isOffline' parameter which will launch Offline Signing mode.

```
templateDelegate.useTemplate(context, templateId, envelopeDefaults, true, ...)
```

Otherwise if you pass 'issOffline' parameter as true, it throws DSSigningException.

Comment: yes I used 'isOffline' parameter as true and it works. When do you plan to release the Online Signing for Android?

Comment: Is there a way to hide/ bypass the Host sign page at the beginning of Docusign ceremony?

Comment: Reg. hiding/bypassing host sign page, you can set 'signing order' for the recipients in the template so that Host signing will happen at the end during signing ceremony. But, if you want to completely skip the signing ceremony of the host, you can remove host from the recipients list in the template. If you are referring to 'Begin Signing' screen(consumer disclosure screen) displayed before starting signing ceremony, you can disable that and take user directly to signing. You can disable presenting 'consumer disclosure' option in Docusign web portal from Admin Settings.

Comment: Host Signing requires begin signing modal to proceed. If you want to bypass this modal use web to select a proper option in Legal Disclosure section in DocuSign web portal.

Comment: Reg. release of Online Signing for android, we are planning to release that feature in Q4.